# HttpListenerRequest.Url when port forwarding

Tags: c#, http, firewall

I have simple http server based on HttpListener. Http server is running on local machine (IP: X.X.X.X:10101) behind the firewall. To make Http server visible for external request i have added port forwarding on firewall from external interface Y.Y.Y.Y:8080 to X.X.X.X:10101.

Now: When i receive request from external host i see that HttpListenerRequest.Url is set to Y.Y.Y.Y:10101 - so its kind of mix between internal and external interfaces (IP belongs to external interface, and port belongs to internal interface).

What is the reason of this behavior? I would expect that url should be Y.Y.Y.Y:8080. Is there any way to "reslove" original url that request was posted to?

Best Regards,
It Man

Answer (score 0):

I seems that firewall modifies http request header, changing external port to local.